# marionette driver giving me issues

Tags: selenium, firefox-marionette

I'm running marionette driver with selenium 2.53. I'm seeing a lot of issues on a ubuntu server v 14.0.

In fact the tests hang. Have there been any issues with marionette version 0.9.0 selenium v 2.53 that I should know about?

I get the error:

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed
```

when running the selenium tests